# Page found with "Plain" permalink but not with "Post name"

Tags: permalinks

I'm working locally on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine, with apache2 server.
I started developing the site on Windows 10 before moving to Ubuntu.

I now have this problem:

When I set Permalinks to "Post name" all pages, except the front page, are not found by the server.

By the way, when moving to Ubuntu I also changed the site url.
However, I did similar changes when moving the site to a remote server with no problem at all.

My .htaccess is writable looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nuritzurgil.co.il/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /nuritzurgil.co.il/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For permalinks to work, you need **mod_rewrite** module enabled on Apache server. Check your Apache configuration and make sure **mod_rewrite** is installed and enabled.

Here is the easy to follow tutorial for Ubuntu 16.04 to enable Rewrite module: [How To Rewrite URLs with mod_rewrite for Apache on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)